# jQuery Cycle: Update currSlide onClick

Tags: jquery, jquery-cycle

I'm using the jQuery Cycle plugin to create an image slideshow. It works great, but I have a minor issue I can't seem to solve. If you click on the "Prev" or "Next" links the slideshow counter doesn't update until after the animation has finished. Ideally the slideshow count would update as soon as you clicked on either of these links, and then the animation would take place.

JSFiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/dD52s/

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a way to do that right now. If it really bugs you that much, perhaps you could try contacting the developer and ask for help.

Comment: Oh, thats too bad. Thanks for looking into it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `after` callback use `before` callback if you want the counter to set before animation begins. Try this

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.slideshow').cycle({
        fx: 'scrollHorz',
        timeout: 0,
        next: '.next, .slideshow img',
        prev: '.prev',
        speed: 600,
        before: onAfter,
    });

    function onAfter(curr,next,opts) {
        var caption = ($(next).index() + 1) + '/' + opts.slideCount;
        $('.counter').html(caption);
    }

   $('.description').cycle({
        fx: 'none',
        timeout: 0,
        next: '.next, .slideshow img',
        prev: '.prev'
    });

});
```

Working [http://jsfiddle.net/dD52s/2/](http://jsfiddle.net/dD52s/4/)

Comment: I tried that, but if you notice in your demo the counter doesn't update the first time you click on next or prev.